# Does ngRouter support "nested" resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to do a few things during the resolve phase of some routes, using ng-router.

1. Get an offer
2. Take the offer data from the first resolve, check if its status is as expected. If it's not, display a message which will redirect the user. If the status is OK, it will resolve the second resolve and load the controller.

Code:

```
resolve: {
    offer: ['$q', '$route', 'viewsService', function verifyOfferStatus($q, $route, viewsService) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      viewsService.getOffer($route.current.params.idoffre)
        .then(function success(data) {
          return deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(function error(err) {
          return deferred.reject(err);
        });

      return deferred.promise;
    }],
    test: ['offer', function(offer) {
      debugger;
      console.log(offer);
    }]
}
```

If I were using ui-router, I would simply have to inject the dependent resolve in `responseData`, but I am getting an `Unknown provider: offerProvider <- offer <- test` error.

Extra info:

- I am using components as my route templates

Comment: this verification is also a promise?

Comment: @dfsq I have updated the code example to show you the actual service call.

Comment: Anyway, not clear what is your problem, you already have everything you need, just resolve/reject as usual. You can nest them as much as you need.

Comment: @dfsq `test` is never being executed because angular throws an error. The error is in the description above.

Comment: @justinledouxweb doesn't your experiment allow answering your own question?

Comment: @JBNizet that's the question... Is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve using ng-router? Getting an error doesn't confirm it's not supported. It confirms something is not working.

Comment: No, it's not supported. The router just does a $q.all() on the promises. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L722

Comment: It's not possible but you don't really need to be able. Just use normal promises routine with new promise returned from one another.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), it is not possible, as `ng-route` only performs a `$q.all()` on the resolve promises.